# error " Could not find or load main class application.Main" in java fx while running the project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am getting an error "Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main"
This project has been cloned with the help of source tree.

This is my main.java class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application
{

    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/GetStarted.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("LOGIN");
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you running it, and from where? Where did you place the class file? Is it in a jar file, or just on the filesystem?

Comment: I am running it on ellipse.The .classpath file exists in the folder of my project.I am confused.

Comment: @James_D I have a question here.After building the JavaFX project with Maven when i try to run the exe file i get this error no matter what i do in every project.If this is too broad i can ask it separately.

Comment: @mistletoe Is the project configured to build automatically? If not, build it (from the Project menu). If so, clean it (also from the project menu) so it will rebuild.

Comment: Yes, the project has been configured to build automatically.